# Why does this complex analytic function statement hold?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I don’t really have any experience in complex analysis so I’m hoping someone can explain why the following statement is true (it is used to prove a lemma necessary to prove Itos representation theorem)

“Since $G()=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $G$ is analytic, it follows $G()=0$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$.”

Why is this the case? If it is the result of a well known theorem, could someone give the actual theorem?

As I understand it, a complex analytic function is simply a function that can be written as a power series at any point. I don’t understand how it being zero on the reals means it must be zero for all complex numbers.

Comment: On the one dimensional case, it is a simple conclusion from the Cauchy-Reimann equations, perhaps there is a generalization of the concept to n dimensions that still allows the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

If $x_2,\cdots,x_n$ are real then $f(z_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ is an entire function of the first variable which vanishes on the real line, so we get $f(z_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)=0$ for all $z_1 \in \mathbb C$. Now consider $f(z_1,z_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and apply the same argument to conclude that $f(z_1,z_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)=0$ for all complex $z_2$, and so on.

Comment: The basic idea is to vary only one variable at a time, keeping $n-1$ variables fixed. Please go through my proof for $n=2$ and you will see what is going on.